# How to push docker images with the associated containers

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I have a docker container in a virtual machines where I am hosting my Postgres database, but when I pull that image to my local machine the container does not show up. I have tried import/export and save/load but still I can't get the container to show in my local machine. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to build containers after pulling in the images.

The simplest way is

```
docker create --name my_container bf141206f773
```

where `bf141206f773` is the image's hash. You can also use its `full_name:tag`.

To start your new container:

```
docker start my_container
```

To enter your new container:

```
docker exec -it my_container /bin/bash
```

If you want to see how I do this in a deployment-environment, check out my Laravel QuickStart project's docker files: https://github.com/phpexpertsinc/laravel_quickstart

Comment: That works, but then how do I connect to the local postgres database, when I try to connect with localhost it says that the database doesn't exist?